# Copy all form data info and paste in format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am able to copy from textbox but i have a html form which contains field names and values. Below

[image]

image has the sample form.enter image description here

When i click on copy to clipboard and paste, it should print the following : -

```
BACK 
TYPE OF PAIN: SHARP
PAIN LEVEL: 9
HOW OFTEN: DAILY 
INJURY RELATED: NONE
INJURY DATE: NONE
HOW LONG: 1 YEAR NOW
CAUSE OF PAIN:ARTHRITIS
WORSE WHEN:BENDING OVER 
TREATMENT TRIED: ALEVE, TYLENOL , PAIN PILLS
```

As screenshot shows, i want to copy form data to clipboard

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so , have you tried any code, please upload some code you have tried.

Comment: i just copy the codes from the previous post.. but i deleted the codes already. but are you able to recreate like that?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite a broad question, but you can start here: https://clipboardjs.com/.

insert at the end of your body

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<!-- Target -->
<input id="foo" value="https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js.git">

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#foo">
    <img src="assets/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
```

JS

```
new ClipboardJS('.btn');
```